# Display line break from mysql text type to ejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I have MySQL table with column **PROJ_ABOUT** which is type **TEXT**.

I inserted multiple rows into this column and now I am trying to diplay this entry in my **Express.js** app using **ejs** engine.

```
    <h2>About project</h2>
    <p><%= rows.PROJ_ABOUT %></p>
```

However, when the text is inserted into ejs file, all line breaks are lost.

```
    **Instead of this:**
    Line 1
    Line 2
    **I get this:**
    Line1Line2
```

I tried getting around this by saving entry to database with `<br />` instead of `'\n'` but instead of getting line breaks I got text with br tags written as common text.

```
    **So i got this:**
    Line1<br />Line2
```

Now, I saw the answers for PHP, but i am using Node.js with ejs templating engine and I am looking for a solution using JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the proper EJS syntax for rendering unescaped HTML, otherwise you will get the escaped strings.

Short answer would be :

```
<!--    V You should use - instead of = -->
<p>   <%- rows.PROJ_ABOUT %></p>
```

this will render your `rows.PROJ_ABOUT` variable as unescaped HTML

Answer (score 1):

Try this EJS tag `<%- %>` instead of `<%= %>`. The first EJS tag **will not** escape HTML.

So just wrap your text with `<br>` to `<%- rows.PROJ_ABOUT %>`

To change line ends like `\n` to `<br>` in your text you can use [nl2br](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nl2br) package (on server-side).

Comment: I used other solution as I just changed \n to br tag and it worked, but If I were to use nl2br, where would i include it?

Comment: I mean, i install it on my project, make require statement on routing page and then will it work in ejs template already?

Comment: Oops! No, you need to call `nl2br()` on server-side. It's my fault

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<p><%- rows.PROJ_ABOUT %></p>
```